# What term describes the relationship between 'collectivism' and 'collectivisation'?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, nouns, terminology, morphology

What is *collectivism*, in terms of grammar, of *collectivisation*?

Put another way:

> Collectivism is the [which word?] of collectivisation?

Another example word pair might be *centralism* and *centralisation*.

Comment: Neither word is derived from the other; both derive from *collective* (it would take considerable research to determine whether *collectivize* is intermediary to both), so they are technically *cognates*, although this is temporally a much closer relationship than those for which the term is usually employed. *Coderivative* might be a useful coinage.

Comment: It [certainly looks](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collectivism%2Ccollectivization%2Ccollectivisation%2Ccollectivise%2Ccollectivize&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) as if *collectivisation* didn't really get started until the late 1920s, by which time *collectivism* had been around at least 30-40 years.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a word describing either the relation of *collectivism* to *collectivisation*, or the reverse (the relation of *collectivisation* to *collectivism*).

They're both just [alternative nominalizations](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/nominalterm.htm) — "a type of word formation in which a verb or an adjective (or other part of speech) is used as (or transformed into) a noun".

Noting [this definition](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=collectivisation&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=qoSWULCIBcK80QXb4oDoAg&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3f622645d8196b60&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917) — "**collectivization**: the organization of a nation or economy on the basis of **collectivism**"— and the fact that ["collectivism" gained currency first](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collectivization,collectivism&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), I suppose one could argue that *collectivization* is a [derivation](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/derivterm.htm) (or *derivative*) of *collectivism*, rather than the other way around.

Comment: I agree with FF's answer, but would like to add that different suffixes can be used to form nouns with different meanings. The _-ism_ suffix is used to form a word that describes _a system, a principle, or an ideology_; _-ation_ is used to make a word that describes _a result or product of some action_. Apart from the two words being derived from the same source, I'm not aware of any defined relationship that would describe a pair of words with these two particular suffixes on the same root.

Comment: @J.R.: Actually, it seems to me that might represent another argument for saying *collectivisation* is a ***derivative*** of *collectivism*. If we allow that the "principle, school of thought" meaning arose *first* in sociopolitical terminology, it's probably reasonable to infer that *collectivisation* as "result of/movement towards collectivism" could be seen as a later term derived "directly" from the earlier one.

Comment: Perhaps so in this case, but, in the general -ism/-ation case, it might be hard to figure out which came first, or if one was directly derived from the other. For example, _minimalism_ can refer to a lifestyle, or to an architectural style, yet an accountant may talk about the _minimalization_ of taxes, and those two words aren't really derived from each other, they simply share a common root.

Comment: @J.R.: Hmm. If my accountant said his business was *minimalization* of taxes, I'd just look for a better-educated accountant who talked of ***minimisation** or **minimising** of taxes* (and ideally, *spelt* it like that, so I'd know he was a Brit! :)

Comment: Please, don't overanalyze it, I was just trying to think of a pair of words to use as an example.  (Nonetheless, I figured someone might call me out on that one, so I wasn't going to use it unless I actually knew for sure that [at least one accountant](http://www.tcorcoran.net/Services) used that term.) If you still don't like that example, though, we could just talk about [mathematicians](http://books.google.com/books?id=u14l14TcwJIC&pg=PA391&dq=minimalization&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TvOXUJLVKu-x0QGo4IHYAg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=minimalization&f=false) instead.